# jQuery / DataTable: Export to Local Server

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I want to export the jQuery DataTable with any file format to local server side. Actually, I am trying to send Excel export file in email. 
But I could not find to do that. I am working on PHP and jQuery. I do not have any idea about that. Therefore I cannot provide you example codes.
I am kindly request your helps.

Thanks.

Comment: please write code what have you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first learn how to export the data to a particular path in an excel file.You can use the same logic as that of creating a table except that in excel the cells are seperated by a "/t" tag and end of line by "/r/n" . You can get an idea of how to export excel from here: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/dataexport/ 
This done , you can then send that file as an attachment in your email.